# Count ID and select it in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to count an item as well select it's value in mySQL db query?

```
SELECT a.id AS item_id,
       b.id AS group_id,
       c.user_id,
       COUNT(c.user_id) AS cnt
```

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: Will this query run with a group by clause?

Comment: Never mind count, that was a part of working query. Adding c.user_id is a bad idea, as I found out... this question needs to be deleted, although I learned something new about nested queries. I thought i figured out what needed to be done, but I was on a false trail.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You need to use a nested query:

```
SELECT
   a.id AS item_id,
   b.id AS group_id,
   c.user_id,
   d.cnt
FROM
   tableA a, 
   tableB b, 
   tableC c, 
   (SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS cnt from tableC) as d --nested query
```

Comment: You could, if MySQL ever starts supporting analytics (specifically, the `OVER` clause on aggregates)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. For example this counts the number of times each table name appears in the information_schema.columns table and also displays it.

```
Select
        count(table_name), 
        table_name 
from 
     information_schema.columns 
group by 
     table_name
```

Apparently Neal thinks somehow sql works differently on the information_schema tables (which would be news to me) here's another example

```
Create table ANomalTable
(
    a_id int,
    b_id int,
    user_id int
);

INSERT INTO ANomalTable
VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO ANomalTable
VALUES (2,2,1);
INSERT INTO ANomalTable
VALUES (3,4,2);
INSERT INTO ANomalTable
VALUES (5,6,2);

SELECT 
    count(user_id),
    user_id
FROm ANomalTable
GROUP BY
   (user_id)
```

which outputs

```
count(user_id) user_id
-------------  -------
2,             1   
2,             2
```

Comment: on any normal table this only returns one row.

Comment: @Conrad, any table that is **not** the information_schema (or any other nativ mysql dbs). in other words a database you create and maintain

Comment: @Conrad. that only reults in 2 results. if the OP wants all the results **and** the count, you cannot do it your way.

Comment: @Neal honestly I have no idea what the OP wants, but you're probably right in that often the case that an inline query is what's needed. BTW you could also put it in the select clause. For example see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494332/sum-from-three-tables-in-ms-sql/6494679#6494679) I gave to a similar question

Comment: @Conrad it is slower in the select clause.